# Most accurate Map of Arda before Beleriand was lost

Tags: the-lord-of-the-rings, tolkiens-legendarium

I am making my own *LotR*-themed Risk game and I am having trouble finding a very accurate map of Arda before Beleriand was lost. This map should include Valinor and Númenor as well.

The best I can find so far appears to be a map from David Day's "Tolkien Bestiary"

[image: Map of Arda]

Comment: Well, Numenor didn't exist until *after* Beleriand was destroyed; you will have to make a choice there.

Comment: You may want to look into [*The Atlas of Middle-earth*](http://www.tolkiengateway.net/wiki/Atlas_of_Middle-earth). It's not perfect, but it's quite comprehensive

Comment: Yes, The Atlas of Middle-Earth is the best there is out there. That map you mentionned is really not accurate. As an exemple, Numenor is supposed to be star shaped, and The Shire would be west of Beleriand, not south... try this one instead: http://www.elvenesse.net/maps/Arda_FirstAge.gif.

Comment: No, the Shire Should be EAST of Beleriand, not south.  The maps illustrated puts Beleriand too far north.  It should be west of Eriador, not north west.  The Iron mountain enclosing Angband should be thousands of miles long, not hundreds.  Of course everything beyond the borders of the published maps is speculation.

Comment: The map you included in your question is widely regarded as the worst map of Arda ever made.

Comment: @Wad Cheber I did not suspect that, as I really enjoyed the rest of the bestiary and art in the book.                          As for Numenor not existing at the time, that's alright. I just wanted an approximate location of every continent that had existed.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

David Day's map is widely regarded as one of the **worst** examples of Arda. His work is often criticised in the Tolkien community. Your best bet is to stitch together a number of maps.

One map superimposes a sunken Beleriand on to Western Middle-earth seen here
[image: A map superimposing the sunken Beleriand onto Western Middle-earth]

The rest of Middle-earth can be seen here:
[image: Map of Middle-earth in the Third Age as it was seen in the Lord of the Rings]

A map of Beleriand which was drawn by Tolkien:
[image: Map of Middle-earth before the destruction of Beleriand and the end of the First Age]

As far as I remember there are no good maps of Arda that include Aman. I can't of the top of my head even remember if there was a map of Aman drawn. Outside of Tolkien's own drawings *The Atlas of Middle-earth* is probably your best shot.

As @Joel pointed out resources on Aman can be found in *The Atlas of Middle-earth*, it's not canon but apparently very good.

Comment: Yes, there are a couple of maps including Aman, in the "Atlas of Middle-earth" by Karen Wynn Fonstadt

Comment: I'm generally reluctant to include any non-tolkien resources but I've been recommended the Atlas of Middle-earth a number of times now, might take a look at it.

Comment: Fonstadt is a professionnal cartographer and she made a really good job, I've been having my copy of it for more than 20 years and it is very accurate, very much alike those of Tolkien and his son (which are not perfect by their own aknoledgement anyway), even though there are small errors (but more in the texts than in the maps), which are listed in the link Jason provided in his comment:

http://www.tolkiengateway.net/wiki/Atlas_of_Middle-earth

Comment: In this superposition beleriand is too small (wrong scale)

Comment: There is now also an interactive Map about all the different ages. http://arda-maps.org/ages/second/ Is this what you are looking for?

Answer (score 13):

You can't get more accurate than a map drawn by Tolkien himself.  Here is one such map:

[image: Tolkien's sketch of all of Middle-earth within the Outer Sea]

And a much [larger](https://farm4.staticflickr.com/3811/18872816155_be70a29d86_o_d.jpg), more legible version of the same map, drawn from Tolkien's original, by Karen Wynn Fontstadt:

[image: Map of Middle-earth by Fontstadt per Tolkien's original; more detail, colour]

Because Númenor and Beleriand didn't exist at the same time, it is impossible to find an accurate map showing both.  Here is Karen Wynn Fontstadt's [map](https://farm1.staticflickr.com/371/19198076643_c424f587d4_o_d.jpg) of Arda in the Second Age, including Númenor (but not Beleriand):

[image: The same view of Middle-earth as the previous map, but updated for the Second Age (Númenor is raised, Beleriand is sunken).]

*Note: Click the links to see the full size maps*

Comment: But there are much more Tolkien drawed images. But exactly the first one here is showing most of the important details Tolkien wanted to set a focus on. About the other pictures, there is a project I just released into Beta: http://arda-maps.org/ it is using 200 different maps and merging them into the three maps you can now freely explore. Hope you like it. =)